# How to use std::async on a queue of vectors or a vector of vectors to sort?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

I am trying to compare `std::thread` with `std::async` in this small example that I came up with for a fun exercise. I generate eight vectors with ten random numbers from 0 to 1000. I then push those vectors into a queue so that I can go ahead and multithread the sorting later. Here is the function I am using to generate the random numbers:

```
std::vector<int> generate(int count)
{
  std::vector<int> newVec(count);
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 mt(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0,1000);

  std::generate(begin(newVec),end(newVec),std::bind(dis,std::ref(mt)));

  return newVec;
}
```

In my thread example, I simply lock the queue, grab a vector out of it, call `std::sort` on it, and push that back into a list of vectors so I can merge it into one final vector in the end. That was easy enough to implement, but I am trying to figure out how to implement this same thing with `std::async` This is what I have tried so far:

```
void work(std::deque<std::vector<int>>& queue, std::list<std::vector<int>> toMerge)
{
  std::vector<int> temp;
  temp = queue.front();
  auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async,sortIt,temp);
  queue.pop_front();
  toMerge.push_back(temp);

}
```

I then realized, that this would not do what I thought it would. As I do not believe this could call itself over and over again. So I tried this one:

```
void work(std::deque<std::vector<int>>& queue, std::list<std::vector<int>> toMerge)
{
  if(queue.empty()
  {
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async[&]{return std::sort(queue.front.begin(),queue.front.end());},work,queue,toMerge);
  }
}
```

But that gave me all sorts of compiler errors that I don't really know how to tackle.

How can I achieve this task?

Full code:

```
void sortIt(std::vector<int>& v)
{
  std::sort(begin(v),end(v));
}

void print(std::vector<int> &v)
{
  for(auto &&e : v)
  {
    std::cout << e << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

std::vector<int> generate(int count)
{
  std::vector<int> newVec(count);
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 mt(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0,1000);

  std::generate(begin(newVec),end(newVec),std::bind(dis,std::ref(mt)));

  return newVec;
}

void work(std::deque<std::vector<int>>& queue, std::list<std::vector<int>> toMerge)
{
  //TODO: Make asnyc work
}

int main()
{
  std::deque<std::vector<int>> queue; 
  std::vector<int> tempA;
  std::vector<int> tempB;
  std::vector<int> finalVec;
  std::list<std::vector<int>> toMerge;

  for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
  {
    queue.push_back(generate(10));
  }

  work(queue,toMerge);

}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. `async` returns `future` with results, you need to call `get` on future to wait until task ends. What is your goal? Do you want to start 8 tasks by async (each task sorts one vector) and at the end merges all sorted vector into list ?

Comment: @rafix07 yes that is exactly it. In fact, I do not need async to merge the vectors. I was going to have the program do that in the end by calling `std::merge` on my list of vectors using `tempA`, `tempB`, and `finalVec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to create vector for holding future objects,
iterate over `queue` and at each iterator call `async` function
to start asynchronous operation - in your case it is sorting of vector.
For each future object you have to call `get` method to retrieve sorted vector.
Obtained sorted vector by `get` is added to `toMerge` list.

```
void work(
  const std::deque<std::vector<int>>& queue, // const added - don't modify queue
  std::list<std::vector<int>>& toMerge) // pass toMerge by reference to store results
{
  std::vector<std::future< std::vector<int> >> tasks;
  for (const std::vector<int>& v : queue)
    tasks.push_back (std::async(
                                [vecCopy = v]() mutable { // copy v into vecCopy 
                                   std::sort(vecCopy.begin(), vecCopy.end()); 
                                   return vecCopy; 
                                }));

  // wait until all tasks are complete
  for (std::future< std::vector<int> >& f : tasks)
    toMerge.push_back(f.get()); // move vector into list
}
```

Lambda which sorts look like:

```
[vecCopy = v]() mutable { // copy v into vecCopy  
      std::sort(vecCopy.begin(), vecCopy.end()); 
      return vecCopy; 
}
```

you don't want to modify `v` from `queue` hence the copy of `v` is made,
the content of `v` is copied into `vecCopy`. Because closure 
keeps `vecCopy` by value you need to put *mutable* keyword to lambda to allow
`vecCopy` to be modified.

Comment: Wow! That was really cool! This is the solution I was looking for, the question I have for you is about `vecCopy`, what is going on when you call `vecCopy = v`? How does `vecCopy` know that it is a vector?

Comment: Is works since c++14, in C++11 you can pass variable into closure by reference `[&v]` - it doesn't work because you cannot call sort on `const v`, or by value `[v] mutable` it also doesn't work because `v` is const. Since C++14 you can name captured value and initialize it, `vecCopy = v` means that closure has `vecCopy` as data member and this vector is copy of `v`. You can google *lambda capture expressions c++14* to see more details.